# How much control does a Ranger have over what triggers "disruptive strike" and how it is used?

Tags: dnd-4e, ranger, immediate-reaction

4e Rangers have access to an Encounter Power called *Disruptive Strike*. The power is triggered by an enemy attacking the PC or an ally of the PC. The power gives a -5 penalty on the attack roll of the attacking creature.

**How much control does the Ranger have when activating and using this power?**

- Can the -5 penalty to enemy attack roll be delayed until a later attack or is the -5 penalty applied only to the attack that triggered the power?
- Does the power automatically trigger for the first enemy that tries to attack in each Encounter, or can the PC choose when the power is triggered?

Comment: Are you asking whether you can use your reaction power but store the actual reaction effect for unleashing at whatever arbitrary time you want (like in the middle of someone's turn three turns later), or are you asking whether you're forced to use your power as soon as it can be triggered and can't say "no, I want to save this encounter reaction power for that guy"?

Answer (score 10):

There is one part of the question that isn't clear and is not addressed by SevenSidedDie: Can you choose to not activate an immediate reaction on the first occurrence of a trigger?

#### Immediate Actions are Choices

Since Immediate Actions are a choice, you can always choose to not activate a power on a trigger. If you choose not to, then you cannot use that power until the trigger occurs again.

For example, with Disruptive Strike, you may choose to not activate it against a minion who attacks, but may choose to use it against the Elite's attack right after instead.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it has to be used right away. Not because it's an immediate action, but because it comes from a power that has just triggered. You don't get to choose when triggered powers take effect, even if going through with them is optional – they apply when, and *only* when their trigger condition happens.

Comment: I see what you're getting at now.

Comment: There aren't very many powers of *any* type that allow you to choose when their effect occurs, and the ones that do usually say you have to pick some time before the end of your next turn or lose the effect.